# How to rotate a CannonJS RigidBody?

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, quaternions, cannon.js

Does anyone know how I can rotate a CannonJS (the physics library) `CANNON.RigidBody`? I'm trying to make the object rotate with the camera, so both are facing the same direction. I know I have to modify the quaternion, but this doesn't work correctly:

```
mPlayer.objectBody.quaternion.set(0, mPlayer.yawObject.rotation.y, 0, 1);
```

It also changes the Y-position of the object, not just the rotation.

[Here's a demo](http://braddodi.com/test/) (WASD to move the red rectangle - which is what I want to rotate)
[Here's the main script](http://braddodi.com/test/_js/render.js)

At the moment it automatically rotates based on the physics. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
I've sort of got it working now. But it doesn't rotate fully (the whole 360 degrees) and the angle it rotates isn't quite right. If someone could take a look and see what's wrong I would really appreciate it! :)

[Same link as before](http://braddodi.com/test/) but the rectangle/body is below the camera now, so I can see if it's rotating correctly.

I added this code to make it rotate:

```
mPlayer.objectBody.quaternion.y = mPlayer.yawObject.rotation.y;
mPlayer.objectBody.quaternion.w = 1;
mPlayer.objectBody.quaternion.normalize();
```

---

To save you looking through the code, `mPlayer.yawObject.rotation.y` is set in the MouseMove event:

```
var onMouseMove = function ( event ) {
    var movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
    var movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;

    mPlayer.yawObject.rotation.y -= movementX * 0.002;
    mPlayer.pitchObject.rotation.x -= movementY * 0.002;

    mPlayer.pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, mPlayer.pitchObject.rotation.x ) );
};
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved the problem with help from the Cannon.JS developer. I'm now using:

```
mPlayer.objectBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0,1,0), mPlayer.yawObject.rotation.y);
```